# Facebook test environment

Tags: facebook, testing, sandbox, facebook-page

I'd like to add test pages to an existing Facebook a test environment;NOTE: I have already created an app, together with test-app & test users on developers.facebook.com. Everything is working fine.

I however need to test my stuff against a variety of Facebook pages, be users, or business pages, all done in sandbox mode (e.g. pages must be private). I haven't seen a quick start guides to do that on FB dev portal, and from what I found with google, others have resorted to create test pages. I'd rather use something that's tied up to an app in particular, so as to keep the testing configuration clean.

Can someone share pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a test user for your app and then use that test user to create a page it will not exist except for other test users of your app.

To create a test user for your app:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. My Apps > (Select your app that you want the test page/test user under)
3. Click the **Roles** tab on the left
4. Click **Test Users** in the tabs on the top
5. Add a test user (if you don't have one)
6. Click **Edit** next to the test user you want to use
7. Click **Login as this test user**
8. Follow the normal steps for creating a page